# Правильно поставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Благодарю, Аню, Машу, за чистоту в классе.

Answer (score 4):

Нет. Запятые перед словом "Аню" и после слова "Машу" лишние. Благодарю (кого?) Аню, Машу  за чистоту в классе.

Comment: А можно просто полюбопытствовать, чем Вы руководствовались, когда поставили запятые в таком неожиданном месте?

Comment: Скорее всего, путаница с обращением (Благодарю, Аня,...).